# When was grandfather in Huntsville Prison?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, texas, imprisonment

A man might be my biological grandfather, but he was in Huntsville prison during the 1950's.

I have some data, but can't figure out when he was in prison, when paroled, when he returned, etc.

According to prison records, his eyes are grey and my mother's are brown. No other brown eyes in the family until her.

This man was born in 1925 Dates of custody start in 1941
Finally paroled 1984

I would love to solve this mystery.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour]. I have removed the name and date of birth for your ancestor candidate because he was born less than 100 years ago and no proof of decease has been included within your question. For details of our privacy policy please see our [help/on-topic].

Answer (score -2):

A man who perhaps was your grandfather was born in Indiana in 1925. Was in the Merchant Marines in 43-44. First imprisoned in Sep.1944 in several Texas prisons. Paroled in 1954. Back in prison in 1955 in San Quentin for 6 and half years till going back to Huntsville till 1964. I know everything there is to know about this person.

Actually the reason I came across the question in the first place was through his name and date of birth. This man was my great uncle. Originally he was incarcerated in 1941 as an juvenile before he was in the Merchant Marines and was in his uniform when he was arrested in the summer of 1944. He was given 50 years for various crimes but was paroled to someone in the salvation army in 1954.He was in Huntsville (along with a few other prisons) in the 40's and 50's. He died in June 1984.

One thing I forgot was I found a marriage (and divorce) record for he and his ex-wife in Feb.1953. in Harris county, Texas... Divorce was May 1954.

Comment: What makes you think the OP's grandfather has/had that name? That name isn't mentioned in the question. The dates don't really match up with those given in the question apart from the birth year. Also, is that man still alive? If so, his details should not be posted here.

Comment: Without proof of decease as outlined in the Privacy Policy in the [help/on-topic] I am going to need to redact the name from this answer and the comment of @HarryVervet.

Comment: All the info you mentioned points to my grandfather of record on my mother's birth certificate. Grandmother lived in Houston (Harris county) and gave birth to my mother there. His parole dates do not appear to match the gestational period. I read his obit in which my mother and uncle were mentioned as step-children. Perhaps there is no biological connection- Uncle met him in 70's or 80's and he denied being his father. I would love to read/ see the marriage and divorce records.  Thanks @HarryVeret